# SQL (DB2) query to get count of top 10% revenue contributing customers

Tags: sql, db2, rows

I work for a telecom company and I need to run a scheme for top valued customers who contributed 10% of total company's revenue in the month. I want to know the count of customers who are eligible for this scheme? I am using SQL DB2.

Ex - In the below table, Sum of the Revenue is 5000 and its 10% is 500, and I want to know the count of minimum number of customers whose sum of revenue would be either 500 or just above 500

```
Customers   Revenue
A   156
B   259
C   389
D   125
E   578
F   321
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret the question as wanting the highest revenue customers whose sum is at least 10% of the total revenue.

You need a cumulative sum for this:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*, sum(revenue) over (order by revenue desc) as cume_rev,
             sum(revenue) over () as tot_rev
      from t
     ) t
where cume_rev <= tot_rev * 0.1;
```

This assumes that there is one row per customer.

EDIT:

For "just above", the `where` clause should be:

```
    where cume_rev - revenue < tot_rev * 0.1;
```

Answer (score 2):

To find all customers where *their* total revenue is at least 10 percent of the overall revenue:

```
select customer
from the_table
group by customer
having sum(revenue) >= (select sum(revenue) * 0.1 from the_table);
```

Your sample data doesn't show this, but this also deals with multiple rows per each customer in the table (your example only has a single row per customer)

The get the count of that:

```
select count(*) 
from (
  select customer
  from the_table
  group by customer
  having sum(revenue) >= (select sum(revenue) * 0.1 from the_table)
) t
```