# calculate to get top n percent of generation

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to understand this query statement.

```
write a query to show % of total profit that the top 10% of businesses generated.
```

`1st` : get total profit from all businesses

`2nd` : get % of all profits generated by very single business

`3rd` : sort that profit % by desc

`4th` : get top 10

that's what I've understood.

But somewhere am thinking its not correct what I've thought.

Can anyone please suggest what could be actual ask of this query ?

```
Note: cant ask back from where I got, because this was in interview :)
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be better to ask an author, because I suspect there are no users who can read someone's mind in the past.

Comment: These questions are similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267026/sql-db2-query-to-get-count-of-top-10-revenue-contributing-customers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262798/sql-how-to-find-top-customers-that-pay-80-of-revenue

Comment: @astentx, true, but that's not possible as of now. would be great if you could share what you think if this statement ? :)

Comment: @KrzysztofSkrzypski, thanks for sharing, but am struggling to understand it. what does it mean <<top 10% revenue contributing customers>> ? I think its same applicable to my statement too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Order the businesses by amount of profit.
2. Take the top 10% of the total number of businesses (with or without ties).
3. Calculate the total profit for that 10% of businesses.
4. Compare it to the total profit for 100% of the businesses.

You can use the `PERCENT_RANK` analytic function to give a percentage rank to the businesses in order of profit and then use conditional aggregation to sum the profit for those businesses with the top 10% profit and compare it to the total profit to get the percentage profit made by the top 10% of businesses:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN pct_rnk <= 0.1 THEN profit END)
       / SUM(profit) * 100 AS percent_profit_for_top_10_percent
FROM   (
  SELECT profit,
         PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY profit DESC) AS pct_rnk
  FROM   businesses
)
```

You can also use:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT SUM(profit)
        FROM   (
          SELECT profit
          FROM   businesses
          ORDER BY profit DESC
          FETCH FIRST 10 PERCENT ROWS WITH TIES
        )
       )
       /
       (SELECT SUM(profit)
        FROM   businesses)
       * 100 AS percent_profit_for_top_10_percent
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE businesses (profit) AS
SELECT  1000 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT  2000 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8 UNION ALL
SELECT  3000 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6 UNION ALL
SELECT  4000 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 UNION ALL
SELECT  5000 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 10000 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1;
```

Both output:

> | PERCENT_PROFIT_FOR_TOP_10_PERCENT |
> | --- |
> | 45 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=36c30f69a9d866209b0c9eb27f3977c1)*

Comment: can you please share the meaning you understood from query statement ?

Comment: ,<<top 10% of businesses generated> here top means in descending order and then 10% of that order.  is it correct ?

Comment: If there are 150 businesses then then you sum the profit for the top 15 businesses (maybe more if you are allowing ties).

Comment: last question, why 10000 is showing 0 in pct_rnk in your first query ?

Comment: @OxanaGrey [`PERCENT_RANK` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/PERCENT_RANK.html#GUID-66A868F5-9EBA-482A-BF8C-09300B9EE165)

Comment: how come 0.1 is 10 percent ? Is it 1/10 ? so 5 percent would be 1/5 i.e 0.2 ?

Comment: 10% = 10 out of 100 = 10/100 = 0.1. 5% = 5 out of 100 = 5/100 = 0.05.